# Difference between page_load and onLoad

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, code-behind

What is difference between page_load and onLoad functions in ASP.NET codebehind?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Load is the `event` and OnLoad is a `method` that raises that event when called
it's just base class implementation that does it of course, and therefore
needs to be called from deriving classes so that events work)

Answer (score 23):

You should probably read the [Page Lifecycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) for more info.

This little bit should help clear up the difference:

> Note that when an event handler is
>   created using the Page_event syntax,
>   the base implementation is implicitly
>   called and therefore you do not need
>   to call it in your method. For
>   example, the base page class's OnLoad
>   method is always called, whether you
>   create a Page_Load method or not.
>   However, if you override the page
>   OnLoad method with the override
>   keyword (Overrides in Visual Basic),
>   you must explicitly call the base
>   method. For example, if you override
>   the OnLoad method on the page, you
>   must call base.Load (MyBase.Load in
>   Visual Basic) in order for the base
>   implementation to be run.

and

> Pages also support automatic event
>   wire-up, meaning that ASP.NET looks
>   for methods with particular names and
>   automatically runs those methods when
>   certain events are raised. If the
>   AutoEventWireup attribute of the @
>   Page directive is set to true, page
>   events are automatically bound to
>   methods that use the naming convention
>   of Page_event, such as Page_Load and
>   Page_Init.

The OnLoad is part of the page and is always called.  You don't need to have a Page_Load method which is just optional extension of the event.

Answer (score 2):

They handle the same event but Page_Load() works only when AutoEventWireup="true".

Answer (score 2):

OnLoad fires the Load event, which Page_Load is a default event handler.