# difference between Page_Load() and OnLoad()?

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between page_load and onLoad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464898/difference-between-page-load-and-onload)

what is the difference between the Page_Load() and OnLoad() event handlers.
do they originate from a different point ?